# How to prove that the lower bound of the Huffman coding problem is $\Omega(n \log n)$?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, lower-bounds, huffman-coding, decision-tree

how to prove that the lower bound of the Huffman coding problem is $\Omega(n \log n)$?

Here Huffman coding problem is Huffman encoding.

For example,

```
Input:
A string with different characters, say “ACCEBFFFFAAXXBLKE”
Output:
Code for different characters:
Data: K, Frequency: 1, Code: 0000
Data: L, Frequency: 1, Code: 0001
Data: E, Frequency: 2, Code: 001
Data: F, Frequency: 4, Code: 01
Data: B, Frequency: 2, Code: 100
Data: C, Frequency: 2, Code: 101
Data: X, Frequency: 2, Code: 110
Data: A, Frequency: 3, Code: 111
```

I already saw that we can know that the bound of the sorting problem is $\Omega(n \log n)$ by using decision tree.

the number of leaves: $n!$ 
(the number of leaves in a half tree with a height of $h) \leq 2^h$ 
$\Rightarrow n! \leq 2^h \Rightarrow h \geq \log n!$

$\Rightarrow \log n! \fallingdotseq n \log n - n = \Omega(n \log n)$

So I thought I could also use the decision tree to get the lower bound of the Huffman coding problem but I am not sure how to construct the decision tree for Huffman coding problem, like how many leaves are needed,...

Please tell me how to construct the decision tree or is my attempt to tackle this proof wrong?

Comment: What is the Huffman coding problem?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It's Huffman encoding

Comment: What is the input, and what is the desired output?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus input: a string with different characters, like “ACCEBFFFFAAXXBLKE”, output: Huffman code

Comment: How is the output presented? Also, instead of answering in the comments, please update your question. Don't add an "UPDATE:" section; instead, just insert the details where appropriate.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for your teaching, I edited it.

Comment: Is the alphabet constant, or could grow with $n$? If the alphabet is constant, then you can compute a Huffman code in $O(n)$. Otherwise, in the comparison-based model, $\Omega(n\log n)$ comparisons are required just to compute the histogram of the data. This follows from the lower bound $\Omega(n\log n)$ on the element distinctness problem (given a sequence of $n$ elements, are all of them distinct?).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what do you mean "grow with " ?

Comment: Is the alphabet fixed, or is it part of the input?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus I still don’t perfectly understand your meanings, but it’s one example of the input.

Comment: What is the size of your alphabet?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sorry, I am not sure and why you need to ask it.